# Should connection pool checking out match the checking in, in MongoDB Performance Events

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance

I am trying to identify a performance issue in one of my applications, with regular "MongoWaitQueueFullException"'s.  I have implemented a set of performance events to try and identify why.

```
        clientSettings.ClusterConfigurator = builder =>
        {
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolCheckingOutConnectionEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.CheckingOutConnectionEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolCheckedOutConnectionEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.CheckedOutConnectionEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolCheckingOutConnectionFailedEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.CheckingOutConnectionFailedEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolCheckingInConnectionEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.CheckingInConnectionEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolCheckedInConnectionEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.CheckedInConnectionEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolAddingConnectionEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.AddingConnectionEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolAddedConnectionEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.AddedConnectionEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolOpeningEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.OpeningEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolOpenedEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.OpenedEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolClosingEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.ClosingEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolClosedEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.ClosedEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionPoolClearingEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.ClearingEventCount++);
            builder.Subscribe<ConnectionCreatedEvent>(e =>
                mongoMonitor.CreatedEventCount++);
        };
```

I then ran a load test (about 1000 clients a second) on a page that makes a database query

These are the results

```
Connection Pool Event   Count
Checking out    64585
Checked out 58416
Checking out failed 7094
Checking in 57119
Checked in  57095
Adding Connection   202
Added Connection    202
Opening 3
Opened  3
Closing 0
Closed  0
Clearing    0
Cleared 0
Created 202
```

The numbers are constantly increasing too - even though there are no current requests, or any database queries happening.

Should the Checking/ed out match the Checking/ed in?

Comment: maybe it's unrelated, if I understood you correctly, you're running 1000 client in your tests, then there is a difference in client behavior when you configure `ClusterConfigurator` (as in your test) and when there is no such delegate (in your application itself). => see next comment

Comment: The difference is related to the fact that when you create a client with the same mongoClientSettings and without `ClusterConfigurator`, all underlying mechanisms including connections are reused (so they're created only once), but if the `clusterConfigurator` is configured, each time when you create a new client, you also create all internal client processes and connections again, to fix it, you should reuse a `ClusterConfigurator` delegate in all your test clients

Comment: Sorry when I say client I mean concurrent web requests essentially - there's only one mongo instance in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  ++ isn't thread safe

Replacing with

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref CheckedOutConnectionEventCount);
```

Resolved the issue and so all numbers matched